# MPU9250 and ESP8266 are not working together with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, mpu6050

I am trying to send IMU sensor data via WiFi using ESP8266. Both MPU9250 and ESP8266 worked individually with 3.3 V when tested, but are not working when interfaced together. I am not sure what the problem is; it looks like the ESP8266 is getting connected to WiFi, but the IMU is having a problem.

First I connected the ESP and the IMU parallel with 3.3 V from the Arduino, but it did not work.
Then I connected the IMU separately with 5 V but still unsuccessful.

Connections of MPU9250

[image: Arduino uno connection with imu]

Connection of ESP8266

[image: ESP8266 connection to arduino uno]

note:-
3.3 supply is common to esp and imu
reset is connected to ground
board selected in Arduino IDE is 'generic ESP8266'

code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#define PubNub_BASE_CLIENT WiFiClient
#include <PubNub.h>
#define PUBNUB_DEFINE_STRSPN_AND_STRNCASECMP
#include "MPU9250.h"

const char *ssid =  "mym404";     // replace with your wifi ssid and wpa2 key
const char *pass =  "786110786";

const char * pubkey = "pub-c-4a9cdbca-5688-4939-a852-f63cf6743980";
const char * subkey = "sub-c-9b4067ae-1293-11e9-b4a6-026d6924b094";

const char * pubchannel = "demo_keyset";
const char * subchannel = "demo_keyset";

MPU9250 IMU(Wire,0x68);
int status;


void setup() {
    /* For debugging, set to speed of your choice */
    Serial.begin(115200);


       Serial.println("Connecting to ");
       Serial.println(ssid); 

       WiFi.begin(ssid, pass); 
       while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
          {
            delay(500);
            Serial.print(".");
          }
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("WiFi connected");

    /* Start the Pubnub library by giving it a publish and subscribe
       keys */
    PubNub.begin(pubkey, subkey);

    while(!Serial) {}

  // start communication with IMU 
  status = IMU.begin();
  if (status < 0) {
    Serial.println("IMU initialization unsuccessful");
    Serial.println("Check IMU wiring or try cycling power");
    Serial.print("Status: ");
    Serial.println(status);
    while(1) {}
  }
}

void loop() {
    // read the sensor
  IMU.readSensor();
  // display the data
  Serial.print(IMU.getAccelX_mss(),6);
  Serial.print("\t");


    /* Publish message. You could use `auto` here... */
    PubNonSubClient *pclient = PubNub.publish(pubchannel, "String(IMU.getAccelX_mss())");
    if (!pclient) return;
    PublishCracker cheez;
    cheez.read_and_parse(pclient);
    /** You're mostly interested in `outcome()`, and,
        if it's "failed", then `description()`. 
    */
    Serial.print("Outcome: "); Serial.print(cheez.outcome());
    Serial.print(' '); Serial.println(cheez.to_str(cheez.outcome()));
    Serial.print("description: "); Serial.println(cheez.description());
    Serial.print("timestamp: "); Serial.println(cheez.timestamp());
    Serial.print("state: "); Serial.print(cheez.state());
    Serial.print(' '); Serial.println(cheez.to_str(cheez.state()));
    pclient->stop();

    /* Wait for news. */
    PubSubClient *sclient = PubNub.subscribe(subchannel);
    if (!sclient) return; // error
    String msg;
    SubscribeCracker ritz(sclient);
    while (!ritz.finished()) {
        ritz.get(msg);
        if (msg.length() > 0) {
            Serial.print("Received: "); Serial.println(msg);
        }
    }
    sclient->stop();

    delay(1000);
}
```

I didn't get any error but here is the serial port message:-

```
.....
WiFi connected
IMU initialization unsuccessful
Check IMU wiring or try cycling power
Status: -1

Soft WDT reset

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffdf0 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 01b0
3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffeec60 40206dd0  
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe8538 4010150d  
<<<stack<<<

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(1,7)
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: wires are connected like above

Comment: so you think that the esp8266 should be able to read the IMU wired to Uno? how?

Comment: I thought sensor readings will go to arduino, which will upload data to wifi through ESP8266. What should i do then? using node mcu?